# What is the significance of utilizing certain letters for variables in Abstract Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For example, say Z_30, or U_8, or S_7.

I understand that these are meant to represent different types of groups - I've heard the phrases "unit groups", "cyclic groups" and "symmetric groups", but what exactly do these mean?

Am I supposed to be able to quantify these? (i.e if I see U_2 I could hypothetically (and incorrectly) say U_2 would have the elements 1,2, and 3??) With no prior knowledge of group theory, this class is difficult for me to grasp and I am drowning as the semester progresses.

Comment: Every single one of these symbols should have a definition somewhere in your course materials.  Look them up!

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_30$ is the integers modulo 30 and $S_7$ is the symmetric group on 7 elements. Your text will absolutely have all of these defined.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick response! I find my current textbook very dense and difficult to go through to understand the nuances of the topic, which leads to my current confusion. Would you happen to have any basic/simple suggestions for where I could read up on these? @EricWofsey

Comment: They do indeed represent groups, but at their basic level they are also a set of elements. They are important sets of elements, hence why the set receives their own special notations. To be exact, your three examples are "the integers modulo $30$" , "the $8$th roots of unity", and "the symmetric group on 7 letters"

Comment: Pinters book introduction to abstract algebra is a great resource if you're just starting out.

Comment: I'll give it a shot - thanks again!

Comment: Maybe your book has an "index of notations" somewhere in the back? By the way, is there any reason why you haven't told us what book it is that's causing you trouble? (If this were a car forum and you were having trouble with your car, you would tell us the make, model, and year of the vehicle you were having trouble with, wouldn't you?)

Comment: In *good* mathematical writing, at the start of a chapter/paragraph/exercise in addition to saying $S_7$, the author will clarify in words what they mean, for example "Let $G = S_7$, the symmetric group on $7$ letters". If they *don't* do this, then just write it in yourself every time you see it! After doing this for a while you will get the hang of the notation.

Comment: None of these notations are completely standard.  $S_7$ is the closest, though fuddy-duddies might insist on $\mathfrak{S}_7$.  $\Bbb{Z}_{30}$ is a barbarism for $\Bbb{Z}/(30)$.  And the roots of unity as a group are isomorphic to the cyclic group of that order.  If you want to call them out as roots of unity you can write $<\zeta>$, $\zeta$ a primitive eighth root of unity.  $U_8$ is a unitary group scheme, not a group of roots of unity.  Big difference!

Comment: *I find my current textbook very dense and difficult to go through* Sure, I understand sometimes it is hard to find exactly what you want. But what did your teacher say when you asked him/her this question? You *did* ask the most knowledgable person about your class's material first, right?

Comment: @rschwieb I asked him about these, and he told me to read the textbook.  The one we are using for this class is by Joseph Gallian-Contemporary Abstract Algebra-Cengage Learning (2016)

Comment: @DumbStudent You found *Gallian* to be dense?  You ain't seen dense yet, apparently :) But I know the feeling. Stick with it and it eventually gets clear.